# Unit and e2e testing a grpc microservice

Tags: node.js, grpc, nestjs

Hi everyone I'm creating a grpc microservice using the nestjs framework. Can anyone give me some advice on how I would test my grpc microservice (unit and e2e).

Answer (score 2):

You can find official doc about microservices e2e in [github](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/integration/microservices/e2e),

em.. unit test demo I'm still looking for,

[grpc-mock](https://github.com/YoshiyukiKato/grpc-mock) maybe a way can do unit test